# Getting cc_cid_status and cc_avs_status from Authorize.net on Magento

Tags: magento, authorize.net

Hello im trying to place an order in **TEST mode** and retrieve the $payment->cc_cid_status and $payment->cc_avs_status but its always empty. Is this normal because i'm in creating an order in **TEST Mode** or do i need to create a script to retrieve it?

The payment method that i use is Authorize.net and i also notice that the transaction ids are always 0.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Don't use Test Mode in your API request, otherwise Authorize.Net won't actually process anything in sandbox or production.

Comment: @rhldr thanks, yeah i contacted them and they say, they doesnt return those cid status and avs status if im in test mode.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Authorize.net and they dont fill up the data in these variables.
$payment->cc_cid_status and $payment->cc_avs_status  since it's in TEST mode.